# Creating list using a frequency list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
age = [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
frequency = [2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1]
output_age = [19, 19, 20, 21, 22, 22, 22, 23, 23, 24, 25]
```

How do we create a new list which adds items from one list a number of times dependant on another list?

Thanks

Comment: By a 'number of times dependant on an another list' what *exactly* do you mean? The number of items or their values or?

Answer (score 8):

Use a list-comprehension:

```
output_age = [i for l in ([a]*f for a, f in zip(age, frequency)) for i in l]
#[19, 19, 20, 21, 22, 22, 22, 23, 23, 24, 25]
```

---

**why?**

We first `zip` together the `age` and `frequency` lists so we can iterate over them in unison. As so:

```
for a, f in zip(age, frequency):
    print(a, f)
```

gives:

```
19 2
20 1
21 1
22 3
23 2
24 1
25 1
```

Then we want to repeat each element, `a`, as many times as `f` determines. This can be done by creating a list and multiplying it. Just like:

```
[4] * 3
#[4, 4, 4]
```

We then need to unpack these values so we wrap this expression in a generator (indicated with brackets) and iterate over that. This flattens the list. Note that there are [alternative ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python) of achieving this (such as using `itertools.chain.from_iterable`).

---

An alternative method would be to repeat the number, `a`, through iterating over a `range` object rather than multiplying a list to get the repetitions.

This method would look something like:

```
output_age = [a for a, f in zip(age, frequency) for _ in range(f)]
#[19, 19, 20, 21, 22, 22, 22, 23, 23, 24, 25]
```

Comment: Thank you but this is is not quite right, this results in 
    output_age = [[19, 19], [20], [21], [22, 22, 22], [23, 23], [24], [25]]

Comment: @jr100 See again, I corrected it

Answer (score 3):

Using `itertools` and `zip`

**Ex:**

```
from itertools import chain
age = [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
frequency = [2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1]

print( list(chain.from_iterable([[i] * v for i,v in zip(age, frequency)])) )
```

**Output:**

```
[19, 19, 20, 21, 22, 22, 22, 23, 23, 24, 25]
```

- **Note:** `chain.from_iterable` to flatten the list.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest and easiest to understand way;

```
age = [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
frequency = [2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1]

output_age = []
for age, freq in zip(age, frequency):
    for _ in range(freq):
        output_age.append(age)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution using `zip` and `range`

```
>>> age = [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
>>> frequency = [2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1]
>>> [a for a,f in zip(age, frequency) for _ in range(f)]
[19, 19, 20, 21, 22, 22, 22, 23, 23, 24, 25]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
age = [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
frequency = [2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1]
new_list = zip(age, frequency)
output_age=[]
for x,y in new_list:
  for i in range(y):
    output_age.append(x)
```

**output:**

[19, 19, 20, 21, 22, 22, 22, 23, 23, 24, 25]

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it using the `sum` function, although this is not recommended for production code:

```
age = [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
frequency = [2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1]
output_age = sum([[age[i]] * frequency[i] for i in range(len(age))],[])
print(output_age)
```

Output:

```
[19, 19, 20, 21, 22, 22, 22, 23, 23, 24, 25]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
import functools
output_age = functools.reduce(lambda x, y:x+y, [[age[i]] * frequency[i] for i in range(len(age))])
```